# Change top bar clock format

Tags: customization, top-bar

How do I change the format of the clock at the top bar?

I want it to be day/month/year. I search an option with gnome tweaks, and dconf, but didn't find anything to change. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: @vanadium Thanks. Hopefully that can be changed on the next release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are limited options to change the display of the clock in Gnome Tweaks, like you discovered. These options will (finally) make it to the main Settings window in forthcoming Gnome version 45.

As usually, there are [Gnome Shell Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/) that can help you out. Seach for "clock format".